# Can I reset to any commit in middle of a rebase?

Tags: git, version-control

I started an interactive `rebase` to edit a few commits. While everything went well I kind of messed it up with the last two commits (I accidentally squashed them). Now I was hoping if I could reset to the commit before editing those last two commits and still be in middle of that rebase that I started. I can see the steps in `reflog` but if I reset hard to any of those steps I can only go back to that commit not that rebase session. Is there any way I could do this or what are my alternatives if I want to only edit the last two commits (because everything before that is fine)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to find the head commit of the branch as it was immediately before the rebase started in the `reflog`...

```
git reflog
```

and to reset the current branch to it (with the usual caveats about being absolutely sure before reseting with the `--hard` option).

```
# Suppose the old commit was HEAD@{5} in the ref log
git reset --hard HEAD@{5}
```

You can check the history of the candidate old head by just doing a `git log HEAD@{5} .`

If you've enabled per branch reflogs you should be able to simply do `git reflog branchname@{1}` as a rebase detaches the branch head before reattaching to the final head. I would double check this, though as I haven't verified this recently. You can do this by adding:

```
[user]
    logallrefupdates=true
```

To be in the safer side make a backup first: `git tag BACKUP`. You can return to it if something goes wrong: `git reset --hard BACKUP`

I found this [link](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html) is very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That didn't exactly solve my problem but definitely gave some insights. The link is super helpful too.

Comment: Glad somehow the info helped you.